# Synchronize js script execution Java

Tags: java, browser, synchronization, locks

I hava a class `BrowserController` with the following method

```
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser;    

...

private final Browser browser;

...

public boolean executeScript(final String script) {
    if (!browser.isDisposed()) {
        log.info("executeScript: {}", script); //$NON-NLS-1$
        boolean result = browser.execute(script);
        return result;
    }
    return false;
}
```

When I press a button in my app, this method is called. The problem is that when I press the button multiple times and fast, this error is thrown

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Another script is already pending
at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.execute(Browser.java:260)
at BrowserController.executeScript(BrowserController.java:58)
```

I tried synchronizing the whole method, also synchronizing on an lock object, I also tried with ReentrantLock but nothing worked. Any idea who can I synchronize this ? I don't want to catch the exception and cancel the execution, I need all scripts to be executed.

Failed synchronization attemps:

first one

```
private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

public boolean executeScript(final String script) {
    if (!browser.isDisposed()) {
        lock.lock();
        log.info("executeScript: {}", script); //$NON-NLS-1$
        boolean result = browser.execute(script);
        lock.unlock();
        return result;
    }
    return false;
}
```

another one

```
private final Object lock = new Object();

public boolean executeScript(final String script) {
    synchronized (lock) {
        if (!browser.isDisposed()) {
            log.info("executeScript: {}", script); //$NON-NLS-1$
            boolean result = browser.execute(script);
            return result;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you just have a class-level boolean that gets set to true once the script is complete.  Then check this boolean is false before trying to run the script again?

Comment: Yes, but than not all scripts are executed.

Comment: Are scripts being executed from elsewhere in the code on that browser object, too? If not, (at least) one of the named methods should have done the job.

Comment: @Fildor no, no other scripts are executed.

Comment: Can you post one of your failed synchronization attempts?

Comment: OK, first snippet: unlock should be inside a "finally" clause... see [JavaDocs of ReentrentLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html). But the second snippet : I would have expected that this one should work.